How to handle CloudFormation update limitations in CI/CD pipelines?
Context: CloudFormation is not able to handle some updates, for example it can't rename path parameters in Api Gateway's route. This sort of updates requires us to deploy a mid-step, usually something like this: "remove the old route, deploy, add the route with new changes back, deploy again". This is just one example, there are similar issues when you have cross-stack dependencies. To be specific, I'm not asking to fix this error.
My question is: How are these scenarios handled in CI/CD? It's easy to do manually but manual deployment from dev's machine is an anti-pattern because of security.
I could set up auto-deploy from every commit and split such deployment to 2 commits. However, most companies do not auto-deploy from master to all environments due to their QA constraints. What are alternative approaches here? How is this typically handled? CloudFormation is full of such issues, so I imagine there must be some kind of best practice to solve it and not do it manually.

You could always write a lambda-backed custom resource and execute that during the stack deployment

I originally wanted to leave a comment but I don't have enough rep. So the answer is honestly, it depends. Usually for my team and I we have our cloud integration set up using Azure Dev Ops where we deploy our services to AWS lambda functions. Our deployment pipeline is a separate process from our actual environments. On one of my old teams, we would change the environment variables manually for our frontend deployments by commenting and uncommenting out the variables, because we never had the time to figure out how to dynamically handle that issue. On another team, we did the same for our .NET backend services using boolean logic gates.
For some of my personal projects, I'm currently dealing with the issue of deploying frontend to both my staging/dev environment and prod environment where I have to manually change the server URI before deploying the latest changes from main into the environments. I haven't had time to figure out a good solution (think the best would be to just write some shell script that will dynamically write to the .env file the server uri based on the flag I pass it).
A former teammate also told me, there is no such thing as best practice, only what is best for your needs after a careful calculation of your trade offs.
